How can I automatically set the current date and time when the checkbox is activated?
I need help, I want every time the check box is active that I have all of them in column G to put the current date and time in column F in its corresponding row.
I have tried to look for code that does it but what I found was that the box is automatically set when I type anything in the box and I only want it to be activated with the check box3
Screenshot
Let the box in column F be set to the current date and time, just click the check box in column G.

Try this:
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Your sheet name" && e.range.columnStart == 7 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    e.range.offset(0,-2).setValue(new Date());
  }
}


Thank you very much, it worked for me, although I think I explained it wrong because I wanted the current date and time in box F and I had it in box E but I changed it, Thank you
